# Scala - access array from parallel for in a threadsafe manner

Tags: scala

I have the following piece of code:

```
//variable arrayToAccess is an array of integers
//anotherArray holds integers also
anotherArray.par.foreach{ item =>
    val mathValue = mathematicalCalculation(item)
    if (mathValue > arrayToAccess.last) {
        //append element
        arrayToAccess :+= mathValue
        //sort array and store it in the same variable
        arrayToAccess = arrayToAccess.sortWith((i1,i2) => i1 > i2).take(5)
    }
}
```

I think that accessing the arrayToAccess variable in that way is not threadsafe. How can I implement the above code in a threadsafe manner? Also, can I control the level of parallelism of anotherArray.par (for instance, only use 2 cores out of 8 available) ? If not, is there a way to control it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overthinking it. 
Just do:

```
arrayToAccess = anotherArray.par
  .map { mathematicalCalculation _ }
  .seq
  .sorted
  .reverse
  .take(5)
```

It yields the same result as your code is intended to, but is thread safe.

*Update* if you are worried about the time sort step would take, you could just select top five in linear time instead:

```
val top(data: Array[Int], n: Int) = {
val queue = PriorityQueue()(Ordering[Int].reverse)
data.fold(queue) { case(q,n) => 
   q.enqueue(n) 
   while(q.size > 5) q.dequeue
   queue
}
.toArray
.sorted
.reversed
```

Regarding configuring the parallelism, I think, this should help: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/configuration

**Update** if you are concerned about the sorting step, you could replace it with a parallel sort or fold into a bounded priority queue in linear time, like this:

```
 def topN(data: Array[Int], n: Int) = {     
   val queue = PriorityQueue()(Ordering[Int].reverse) 
   data.foldLeft(queue) { case (q, x) => 
     q.enqueue(x)
     while(q.size > n) q.dequeue
     q
   }.dequeueAll.reverse
```

Comment: `.seq.sorted.reverse.take(5)`

Comment: If the anotherArray variable is huge, sorted method and reverse method will take time, will it not? Especially if it is a more complex sort method.

Comment: @Sonex, it is not any more "huge" then the original array. Consider, that if the latter is "huge", your approach would sort and re-sort the output a "huge" number of times. That's likely not any faster, than sorting the merged result once. If you are concerned about parallelism, you could use a parallel sort and merge (with limit), but I think that would be an overkill.

Comment: @Sonex or just `.fold` into a (bounded) `PriorityQueue` in linear time.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more your last comment?

Comment: @Sonex, btw, if your array is really huge, take a look at Spark. Your example will look as simple as: `sc.parallelize(anotherArray).map(mathematicalCalculation).top(5)`, and utilize the whole cluster.